# Web app reload issue in Groovy/Grails Tool Suite

Tags: grails, web-applications, groovy, reload, grails-2.4

I have ggts-bundle bundle 3.6.1 64 bit with JDK 7 (jdk1.7.0_67) on Win7 64bit.

I have grails home setup as GRAILS_HOME and grails version grails-2.4.3.

When i create a new action/method in the controller class in the tool suite and hit save and refresh the browser, it doesn't reload the changes in the application.

I even modified BuildConfig.groovy and added the following

```
grails.reload.enabled = true
```

I also tried with grails `-reloading run-app`

Nothing seem to reload the changes, I have to stop the server and restart it and then
it reflects the changes.

I am sure there's something i can do to have it reload the app.

I read online and tried other suggestion in questions on stackoverflow before i posted this.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Did you end up getting a solution to this?

I've just tried this out in GGTS and it looks like there is no problem.

Version: 3.6.3.RELEASE
Build Id: 201411281415
Platform: Eclipse Luna SR1 (4.4.1)
OS: Win7 64bit

I'm working on a plain vanilla (unmodified) install with default settings.

Using a simple Grails project, with a simple HelloController.groovy and a couple of GSPs... corresponding to two methods inside the controller. Launch the server...

Tried out two scenarios to see what happened, back in the IDE...

1. modify some simple output text in one of the GSPs, save, refresh the browser... yep, no problem, the change shows up
2. modify the HelloController.groovy to tell one of the methods to use a different GSP, save, refresh the browser... again, no problems, the change is reflected.

Note. I did have to wait a few seconds in scenario 2 for the IDE to notice the change and to recompile

Perhaps try updating your instance of GGTS to the latest release to see if that makes a difference?

Hope this helps.